# vectorizations of matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I have many 3*2 matrices(A1,A2,A3..), and each of the 3*2 is a draw. In the case two draws, we have a 3*4 ( we horizontally stack each draw of A1,A2). Clearly, it is easier for me to draw the 3*4 matrix (A) as a larger matrices once instead of draw a 3*2 over and over again.

But I need to perform a matrix multiplication for each draw(each A1,A2...) to a matrix B. Say A1*B, and A2*B ...AN*B

```
#each draw of the 3*2 matrix
A1 = np.array([[ 0,  1],
              [ 4,  5],
              [ 8,  9]])

A2 = np.array([[ 2,  3],
              [ 6,  7],
              [ 10, 11]])

# A is [A1,A2]
# Easier to draw A once for all  (the larger matrix)
A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

b = np.array([[ 0,  1],
              [ 4,  5]
              ])

desired output
array([[ 4,  5, 12, 17],
       [20, 29, 28, 41],
       [36, 53, 44, 65]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "draw'?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga,  A1,A2..... are drawn from some distributions, they are similar.

Comment: So you want `np.hstack([A1.dot(b), A2.dot(b)])` but using `A` instead?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to stack the draws horizontally? You'll want your A matrix to be of the shape (n_draws, 3, 2) so you can use [numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to vectorize. Numpy's random-generators should all accept a 3-d input shape

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes, using A instead of A1 or A2

Comment: @pstjohn, I need it in this format so I can further perform some matrix operations on the desired output. If it is in this way, it seems I can perform element wise operation easier later.

Comment: *elementwise* operations should be the same. I think @psrtjohn is right. This is broadcasting behavior, no?

Comment: @pstjohn, If I put it in a 3-d, when I need to compute some statistic for each draw of A1,A2, then I have to loop over the A1,A2 dimention, right?

Comment: I'm assuming it would be easier to compute from a (n,3,2) then one that is block-delimited. I.e., A.std(0) would give you (A1.std(), A2.std()). Not sure how you'd do that with them stacked.

Comment: @pstjohn, I am not familiar with 3-d structure, I will try. Basically, what I am doing is Y=beta*X, only Y is [y1,y2...] , X is [x1,x2...]. In this way, it is just like simple element-wise operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reshape matrix A to 2 columns so that it is conformable to `b`, do the matrix multiplication, and then reshape it back:

```
np.dot(A.reshape(-1, 2), b).reshape(3, -1)

#array([[ 4,  5, 12, 17],
#       [20, 29, 28, 41],
#       [36, 53, 44, 65]])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are unsure about how to store/stack the incoming arrays, one way would be stacking those as a `3D` array, such that the each of those incoming arrays are *index-able* by its first axis -

```
a = np.array((A1,A2))
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: a = np.array((A1,A2))

In [144]: a.shape
Out[144]: (2, 3, 2)
           |-----------------> axis of stacking
```

Then, to get the equivalent output of matrix-multiplications of each incoming array with `b`, we could use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) on the `3D` stacked array `a` with `b`, thus losing the last axis from `a` and first from `b` in the sum-reduction, like so -

```
out = np.tensordot(a,b,axes=((2),(0)))
```

Let's have a look at the output values and compare against each matrix-multiplication with `A1`, `A2`, etc. -

```
In [138]: out[0]
Out[138]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [20, 29],
       [36, 53]])

In [139]: out[1]
Out[139]: 
array([[12, 17],
       [28, 41],
       [44, 65]])

In [140]: A1.dot(b)
Out[140]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [20, 29],
       [36, 53]])

In [141]: A2.dot(b)
Out[141]: 
array([[12, 17],
       [28, 41],
       [44, 65]])
```

Thus, essentially with this stacking operation and later on `tensordot` we have :

```
out[0], out[1], .... = A1.dot(b), A2.dot(b), ....
```

**Alternative to `np.tensordot` -**

We could use a simpler version with [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), to get the same output as with `tensordot` -

```
out = np.matmul(a,b)
```

On Python 3.5, there's an even simpler version that replaces `np.matmul`, the [`@ operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) -

```
out = a @ b
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if not needed for the calculation `einsum` can help us think through the problem:

```
In [584]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A1,b)
Out[584]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [20, 29],
       [36, 53]])
In [585]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A2,b)
Out[585]: 
array([[12, 17],
       [28, 41],
       [44, 65]])
```

`A` is (3,4), which won't work with the (2,2) `b`.  Think of it as trying work with a doubled `j` dimension: `'i(2j),jk->i?k'`.  But what if we inserted an axis?  'imk,jk->imk'?  Or added the extra dimension to `i`?

```
In [587]: np.einsum('imj,jk->imk', A.reshape(3,2,2),b)
Out[587]: 
array([[[ 4,  5],
        [12, 17]],

       [[20, 29],
        [28, 41]],

       [[36, 53],
        [44, 65]]])
```

The numbers are there, just the shape is (3,2,2).

```
In [590]: np.einsum('imj,jk->imk', A.reshape(3,2,2),b).reshape(3,4)
Out[590]: 
array([[ 4,  5, 12, 17],
       [20, 29, 28, 41],
       [36, 53, 44, 65]])
```

Or you could build `A` from the start so that `mij,jk->mik` works (`@Divaker`)

`@Psidom`:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A.reshape(3,2,2).reshape(-1,2) ,b).reshape(3,-1)
```

`@piRSquared':

```
'kj,jI->kI`
```

Comment: I'll be revisiting this one.  I want to get good with einsum.

Answer (score 2):

Shift you perspective.  You are locking yourself into `3 x 2` unnecessarily.

You can think of `A1` and `A2` as `2x3` instead, then `A` would be

```
array([[ 0,  4,  8,  2,  6, 10],
       [ 1,  5,  9,  3,  7, 11]])
```

Then take the transpose of `b = b.T`

```
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5]])
```

So that you can do you operation

```
b @ A

array([[ 4, 20, 36, 12, 28, 44],
       [ 5, 29, 53, 17, 41, 65]])
```

Let your "draws" look like this

```
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 9))
A

array([[7, 2, 1, 0, 9, 9, 1, 0, 2],
       [8, 6, 1, 6, 6, 2, 4, 2, 9]])

b @ A

array([[32, 24,  4, 24, 24,  8, 16,  8, 36],
       [47, 32,  6, 30, 39, 19, 21, 10, 47]])

​
```